# Constraints UIImage stretched and alignment

Tags: ios, iphone, interface-builder

I am very very new to constraints, I have always had an issue with them. I have a logo, 2 text feilds and a button, what I am trying to do is get them to be placed in the same spot regardless the size of the device (centered and middle top position) I tried adding the missing Constraints but it stretched out my image and everything is getting massive on `iPads` and the look not to be in the same position. I have attached screenshots, I have also created an example app with the one scene.

[![enter image description here][1]][1] 
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

What am I doing wrong? Why are these so hard?

I have tried what matt suggested and the end result was this....the logo covers everything, but I get errors now :(

```
   [![enter image description here][3]][3]
   [![enter image description here][4]][4]
   [![enter image description here][5]][5]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Isa.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLZcj.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYqjQ.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w08GS.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKwh8.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use Stack Views to place all the elements vertically.
2. Then make your stack view centre vertically and horizontally within the container/superview.
3. Lastly, make stack view top, bottom, leading, trailing anchors greater than equal to zero, so that it never goes out of the screen bounds.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that

Comment: Try reading about StackViews, build your layout using stack view first. https://www.raywenderlich.com/160646/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views-2